# R - Using reshape() to turn data frame into a two column matrix

Tags: r

I've tried using many variations of the reshape() function (reshape2 package) to turn a data frame of different factors into a two column matrix, but I've been unsuccessful. I also need to ignore blanks. Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

Code Bucket1 Bucket2

1 Green Blue

2 Green (Blank)

3 (Blank) (Blank)

4 (Blank) Blue

INTO:

Code Bucket

1 Green

1 Blue

2 Green

4 Blue

Can anybody help with reshape()?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question directly, but there is an excellent `reshape2` tutorial here: http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html. Once you figure it out, you should post your solution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: I found this [one](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12/paper) from Journal of Statistical Software very helpful by Hadley himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  library(data.table)

  dat <- as.data.table(your_original_data.frame)

  dat[, c(Bucket1, Bucket2), by=Code]
     Code    V1
  1:    1 Green
  2:    1  Blue
  3:    2 Green
  4:    2    NA
  5:    3    NA
  6:    3    NA
  7:    4    NA
  8:    4  Blue

  ## To drop the NA's 
  dat[, c(Bucket1, Bucket2), by=Code][!is.na(V1)]
     Code    V1
  1:    1 Green
  2:    1  Blue
  3:    2 Green
  4:    4  Blue

  ## if they are actually called "(Blank)" use 
  dat[, c(Bucket1, Bucket2), by=Code][V1 != "(Blank)"]
```

---

update:  To convert your factors to characters:

```
   colsToConvert <- setdiff(names(dat), "Code") # or manually type them 
   dat[, c(colsToConvert) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = colsToConvert]
```

Comment: Instead of returning "Green" and "Blue", my measure values are returning as "1"s. How do I return the factor names?

Comment: convert them to character first

Answer (score 2):

The **reshape2** package contains a `melt` function this is for converting datasets from *wide* to *long* format.  There is a `reshape` function, which is part of the **stats* package, which is also useful for reshaping data but is not a function I know well.

To reshape data that you've described, you can use `melt` as follows.  I'm guessing your blanks are `NA`, so I use the `na.rm` argument to remove them.  I use the `value.name` argument to name the new column that is created.

```
melt(dat, id.vars = "Code", na.rm = TRUE, value.name = "Bucket")
```

Result:

```
  Code variable Bucket
1    1  Bucket1  Green
2    2  Bucket1  Green
5    1  Bucket2   Blue
8    4  Bucket2   Blue
```

This doesn't give the exact output you requested, as you want your final dataset in a specific order and without the new `variable` column.  You can use some of the handy functions from the **dplyr** package to remove the extra column (using `select`) and order by `Code` (using `arrange`), although there are certainly other ways to manipulate the result after `melt`ing.

```
require(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    melt(id.vars = "Code", na.rm = TRUE, value.name = "Bucket") %>%
    select(-variable) %>%
    arrange(Code)
```

Now the result looks like:

> ```
>   Code Bucket
> 1    1  Green
> 2    1   Blue
> 3    2  Green
> 4    4   Blue
> ```

Comment: you could skip `dplyr` altogether and simply use    `dat.melted$variable <- NULL`  `dat.melted <- dat.melted[order(dat.melted$Code)]`